How to access a Windows server via Ansible if the certificate has died?
The situation is this: there are hosts whose certificates have died.
Accordingly, when you try to knock on the server, Ansible issues (for example):
ansible -l 'My-Server|xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' -i hosts -m win_ping all My-Server|xx.xxx.xxx.xxx | UNREACHABLE! => { "changed": false, "msg": "certificate: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))", "unreachable": true }
It is clear that you can go to the server and re-upload the certificates. But what if there are more than a hundred of these servers?
I'm not an Ansible expert, but for some reason it seems to me that there must be a way to somehow bypass certificate verification in order to remotely distribute them across all servers.
If anyone knows, please tell me.
I really don’t want to crawl to each server with my hands separately.
-k and validate_certs: false - did not want to work.

Here's what I have.  I did not create any certificates:
ansible_user: ansible
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore

